# Can't run Celery worker using Celery, Flask, and RabbitMQ: unable to load celery application

Tags: python, flask, celery

When I run `celery -A app.celery worker --loglevel=INFO --pidfile=''` I get back the following:

```
Usage: celery [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Error: Invalid value for '-A' / '--app':
Unable to load celery application.
'nonetype' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins'
```

To the best of my understanding, in `celery -A [name].celery...` `[name]` should be the file where the Celery instance is created and held, which in my case is `app.py`.
This is my first time working with Celery, so would love help here!

My file structure is as follows:

```
--app
   -- app.py
   -- celery_config
      -- __init__.py
      -- flask_celery.py
```

**`app.py`**

```py
from flask import Flask
from celery_config.flask_celery import make_celery

# Create app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_envvar("APP_SETTINGS")

...

# Setup Celery
celery = make_celery(app)
```

**`flask_celery.py`**

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name)
    celery.conf.update(
        result_backend=app.config["CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND"],
        broker_url=app.config["CELERY_BROKER_URL"],
        timezone="UTC",
        task_serializer="json",
        accept_content=["json"],
        result_serializer="json"
    )
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

Turns out since I was running the command from inside the `app` directory I needed to run `celery -A celery worker --loglevel=INFO --pidfile=''` rather than `celery -A app.celery worker --loglevel=INFO --pidfile=''` -- `-A app` searches for `celery` within the directory `app`, but I was already in that directory. I only realized this after finding [this](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1485#issuecomment-26726649) GitHub comment.

UPDATE: This was also not the answer, the issue was that I was expecting running the Celery worker to pick up my `.env` variables, which it doesn't do because it's not a Flask-specific package. I had to export my `.env` variables into my local environment because it was trying to instantiate the app's database without the `DATABASE_URL` variable. `celery -A app.celery worker --loglevel=INFO --pidfile=''` was the right command.